# Canvas does not capture entire frame of video

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm trying to use a canvas to extract/capture the frame of a video but it seems to not work for certain videos.

[Here is a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pemw9g80/1/) I found in which the full frame capture works. However, if you change the video source from http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 to https://public.lookielooapp.com/my-video.mp4 you'll see full frame capture does *not* work when you click the `Capture` button.

I've tried all sorts of different things like setting the height and width properties of the video and canvas, playing around with the `dx` and `dy` parameters and changing the dimensions of the video (https://public.lookielooapp.com/cropped.mp4 (480x120 pixels) and https://public.lookielooapp.com/cropped2.mp4 (480x480 pixels)). None of these solutions worked.

How can I get the above fiddle to correctly capture the full frame of a video of mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by setting both the video and the canvas to the same dimensions: https://jsfiddle.net/e1dfw59a/

```
<video id="video" src="https://public.lookielooapp.com/cropped2.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls height="200px" width="200px"></video><br/>
<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button> <br/><br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

Was just a hunch but it seems to do the trick!